# Express Validator unexpected token error on EC2 instance but works fine on local machine

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, express-validator, unexpected-token

[terminal errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FLL7I.png)

I'm trying to host an API on an EC2 instance for a class project. On my local machine (Mac mini, 13.4.1, M2 chip) I enter the repository, run `npm start`, everything works. Through SSH I've cloned the repository from github onto an EC2 instance running Ubuntu, and if I enter that repository and try to start it, I get an unexpected token message in regards to something in express validator.

I looked to the file that the error was pointing to, and the unexpected token in question is also present in the code on my local machine (they're identical) so I'm not sure what could be causing this.